# Definition of "deterministic" semantics in While language

Tags: semantics

I came across this definition in my book but I'm not sure that I understand it correctly.
[image]

Isn't this the same as saying: $\langle S, s\rangle \rightarrow s = \langle S, s\rangle \rightarrow s$ implies that $s=s$? Why do they use a different prime symbol here even though they are the same statement $S$  being executed on the same state $s$.

2nd Question:
How does this statement by the author above allow us to "uniquely determine a final state s' if (and only if) the execution of S terminates"

I think I'm missing the point here because this definition came after **Induction on the Shape of Derivation Trees**.

3rd Question: How will this proof help us perform induction on the shape of derivation trees?

Comment: 1st Equality of a state with itself is implicit, the statement would be silly.

Comment: 2nd This is a definition, there is nothing "allowed".

Comment: Please heed [How to reference material written by others](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come back to this as I solved it but forgot to post my reasoning. The statement above simply states that if we execute a statement S on a state s twice, the resulting state should be the same. Hence, we can "determine" the final result unambiguously.